# How to show button on click of link button of gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a grid view and inside that i have some link button. What I am trying to do is when i clicked on link-button then two more buttons which is outside of grid view should be shown.
I searched it on google and i found some solutions as well. I set command name of linkbutton and on RowCommand event i write below code. But still those buttons are not shown to me.
Can you please help me.....

Code of Gridview:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Action</legend>
                <table border='0' align='center'>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnexptocsv" runat="server" Text="Export To CSV" Enabled="False" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnexptoexcel" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" Enabled="False" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updgrd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Complaint Count </legend>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grd_ComplaintCount" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Complaint">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalComplaint" CommandName="lnkTotal" Text='<%#Bind("TotalComplaint") %>'
                                        CommandArgument="Total"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Open Complaint">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalOpenComplaint" CommandName="lnkOpen"
                                        Text='<%#Bind("TotalOpen") %>' CommandArgument="Open"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Closed Complaint">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalCloseComplaint" CommandName="lnkClosed"
                                        Text='<%#Bind("TotalClose") %>' CommandArgument="Closed"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Reassigned Complaint">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalReassignedComplaint" CommandName="lnkReassign"
                                        Text='<%#Bind("TotalMemberReAssign") %>' CommandArgument="Reassigned"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Observation Complaint">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalObservationComplaint" CommandName="lnkObeservation"
                                        Text='<%#Bind("TotalObservation") %>' CommandArgument="Observation"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Legend_Remark"></asp:Label></legend>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grd_ComplaintDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
                        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="MemberComplaintID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="frmComplaintActionDetails.aspx?CID={0}"
                                DataTextField="MemberComplaintNo" HeaderText="Complaint No" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberCode" HeaderText="Member Code" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentName" HeaderText="Service Area" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ComplaintName" HeaderText="Type Of Complaint" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AutoEscalation" HeaderText="Auto Escalation" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ManualEscalation" HeaderText="Manual Escalation" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ComplaintDate" HeaderText="Complaint Date" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastActionTakenBy" HeaderText="Last Action TakenBy" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastActionDate" HeaderText="Last ActionDate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Severity" HeaderText="Severity" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ComplaintAction" HeaderText="Complaint Action" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code of Rowcommand event:

```
Protected Sub grd_ComplaintCount_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grd_ComplaintCount.RowCommand
    ComplaintCount_Detail(e.CommandArgument)
    If e.CommandName = "lnkTotal" Then
        btnexptocsv.Enabled = True
        btnexptoexcel.Enabled = True
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "lnkOpen" Then
        btnexptocsv.Enabled = True
        btnexptoexcel.Enabled = True
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "lnkClosed" Then
        btnexptocsv.Enabled = True
        btnexptoexcel.Enabled = True
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "lnkReassign" Then
        btnexptocsv.Enabled = True
        btnexptoexcel.Enabled = True
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "lnkObeservation" Then
        btnexptocsv.Enabled = True
        btnexptoexcel.Enabled = True
    Else
        btnexptoexcel.Enabled = False
        btnexptocsv.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

My Question :How to Show Buttons (which is outside of grid view) after Link Button Clicked
(which is inside of gridview)

Comment: Are you able to debug this to make sure your event is wired up?  I don't see the event OnRowCommand="" on your grid.  Do you have AutoEventWireup="true" at the top of your page?

Comment: Yes Dave, AutoEventWireup is set it to "True" and when i debug control comes to OnRowCommand event of gridview

Comment: Is your page_load event resetting the screen on post back?

Comment: Hi dave, thanks for your reply... The code which i have written in page load event is ::: If Not IsPostBack Then

                pnl_ReportDetails.Enabled = True
                btnShow_Click(sender, e)
                div_Msg.InnerText = ""
                btnexptocsv.Visible = False
                btnexptoexcel.Visible = False
            End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your buttons inside the UpdatePanel

Comment: Can you post your code with buttons inside the UpdatePanel please?

Comment: Ok thanks, what I meant initially is to put your buttons inside the same Update panel as your GridView. I reckon the rest of your code is working, it's just not refreshing the state of your buttons as they are outside the UpdatePanel. If you put everything inside one big UpdatePanel, it should work :)

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="showdownloadbtn" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnexptocsv" runat="server" Text="Export To CSV" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnexptoexcel" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Thanks for your reply scott... But it is still not working... i have updated code like this : I paste the code just above grd_ComplaintCount.

Comment: That's great mate. What did you end up doing to get it working?